# Javascript regexp match numbers separated by non-numeric characters

Tags: javascript, regex

I would like to get all the numbers composed of 4 digits. Before and after there should be 2 non digit characters or no characters at all.

This is what I have so far. In this example the correct result would be only "0000" but it also matches 1234, 4567, 5678.

What am I missing ?

Js fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/M8FYm/3/

Source:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <title>Regex test</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            pattern = '(\D{2})?('+'([0-9]{4})'+')(\D{2})?';

            var regexp = new RegExp(pattern, "g");
            var string = $('.test').html();

            while (match = regexp.exec(string)) {
                console.log(match);
            }
        })
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <p class="test">
        1234 4567 67
        0000  345
        456 23  0000
        12345678
    </p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var test = 
"1234 4567 67\n" + 
"0000  345\n" +
"456 23  0000\n" +
"12345678";

test.match(/(^|\D{2})\d{4}(\D{2}|$)/gm)
// => ["0000  ", "  0000"]
```

The Regex looks for either the start of a sentence or 2 non-digits, followed by 4 digits, followed by either the end of a sentence or 2 non-digits. The `/m` modifier makes the `^` match beginning of lines and `$` the ending of lines, not just the beginning and ending of the whole string.

Answer (score 1):

The test string on your example here is not the same as the one on jsfiddle. By adding the correct spacing (2) and the multi-line modifier (m) to a revised regexp it should return the desired result:

```
/\D{2}[0-9]{4}\D{2}/gm
```

result:

```
0000
0000
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/Ebxfj/